# Reference checkbox name/value in a subroutine

Tags: vba, checkbox, userform, subroutine

Is there a way to pass a checkbox value from a userform? I've seen it done when the checkbox is on the worksheet but I haven't been able to get it to work when it comes from my userform.

I have several repeating if statements and the only difference between them is the name of the checkbox. I'm sure there's a simple fix that I just haven't found yet. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: included code

```
If LockboxCheckBox.Value = True Then
    If IsEmpty(wsInput.Cells(emptyRow, productCol)) Then
        wsInput.Cells(emptyRow, productCol).Value = LockboxCheckBox.Caption
    Else: wsInput.Cells(emptyRow, productCol).Value = wsInput.Cells(emptyRow, productCol).Value & ", " & LockboxCheckBox.Caption
    End If
End If
```

I want to make this a small subroutine and need to pass the checkbox.value as well as the checkbox.caption to it when I call it.

Comment: Range("a1").value=check box.value if I get what you need :-)

Comment: @newguy That's if the checkbox was on the worksheet. I get that you can do that. I haven't been able to find a way when the checkbox value is coming form a userform. I have several checkboxes on a userform and I'd like to pass that value to a subroutine.

Comment: @ChasEsau then I think Nathan has already  answered that. Like this `var = checkbox1.value`

Comment: What's not clear is what kind of action/event would trigger this? It's a question of how to interact with the controls on the UserForm - we don't have enough context... You can almost certainly do what you propose, but in order to describe *how* we need more background.

Comment: @CindyMeister The user fills out a userform, that has several checkboxes. All the code works, I just have several repeating if statements and the only thing that changes in them is the name of the checkbox. I was hoping to tidy up a bit and just call to a subroutine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code example demonstrates how to pass a Checkbox control on a UserForm to another procedure, get the checkbox's value and caption, and do something with them.

Note that I choose to pass the checkbox, rather than the value and caption as two parameters, as this will reduce the amount of code you need to type.

```
Private Sub btnOK_Click()
    Dim chk As MSForms.CheckBox
    Set chk = Me.CheckBox1
    ProcessCheckBox chk
    ProcessCheckBox Me.CheckBox2
End Sub

Sub ProcessCheckBox(chk As MSForms.CheckBox)
    Dim chkVal As Boolean
    Dim chkCap As String

    chkVal = chk.value
    chkCap = chk.Caption
    If chkVal = True Then
        Debug.Print chkCap & " is true"
    Else
        Debug.Print chkCap & " is false"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.